# import elliptical arc from dxf

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing, autocad

I have a problem that made me pull my last hair of my head. 
I'm struggling to reproduce an angled elliptical arc in 
my c# winform application using data extracted from DXF.

Data as follows:

```
Centerpoint at X                                  : 597,5; 
Centerpoint at Y                                  : 185; 
Endpoint of major axis, relative to the center (X): 35,9651502358374;
Endpoint of major axis, relative to the center (Y): 60,0542085828599; 
Ratio of minor axis to major axis                 : 0,35714285714286; 
Start parameter                                   : 4,78575772944812;
End parameter                                     : 7,78061288491105;
```

The code:

```
float ex = 597,5;                              //Centerpoint at X
float ey = 185;                                //Centerpoint at Y                                
float exb = 35,9651502358374;                  //Endpoint of major axis (X)                         
float eyb = 60,0542085828599;                  //Endpoint of major axis (Y)                              
float EllipseRatio = 0,35714285714286;                            
double sa = 4,78575772944812;                  //Start parameter                              
double ea = 7,78061288491105;                  //End parameter
sa = double.Parse(exb.ToString()) * Math.Cos(sa) +     //Now it's a Start angle
     double.Parse(eyb.ToString()) * Math.Sin(sa);
ea = 2 * double.Parse(exb.ToString()) * Math.Cos(ea) + //Now it's a sweep angle
     double.Parse(eyb.ToString()) * Math.Sin(ea);
double angle = Math.Atan(exb / eyb);                   //Rotation angle 
Graphics ellipse = this.CreateGraphics();
ellipse.TranslateTransform(ex, ey);                    //So I can rotate at center
ellipse.RotateTransform(float.Parse(angle.ToString()));

ellipse.DrawArc(PreviewPen, (0 - exb), eyb, 2 * exb, 2 * eyb * EllipseRatio, 
                            float.Parse(sa.ToString()), float.Parse(ea.ToString()));
```

It should look like this;
[image]

Instead it looks like this:
[image]

As You can see, all the shapes are ok, except the ellipse.

I just can't get it right. Eider the position is wrong, or the 
orientation is wrong, size, shape, angle...

At some point i got close, but then my thinking engine just blew up.

I'm not using e.graphics.

Please help in details if you can.

Comment: We need more details to help you here. What are you using to display/draw this? Is there some code you wrote to translate this data into objects to be drawn? There can be lots of little things that can go wrong in the code, so try to get the same problem to happen on a simple example and post the code for us so we can help :)

Comment: Thank You for trying to help me. I've just added a code I'm using. In this version there is an elliptical arc with EVERYTHING wrong from what it should be with given parameters.   Thank You again for trying to help.

Comment: @Jeff Not a single answer in 24h. Question too boring or too hard? :)

Comment: I'm not really sure how to get this to draw myself. Could you provide some graphical examples of what it should look like and what it looks like now?

Comment: @Jeff There You go. As You can see, among other shapes I have spherical arcs in my drawing and they work fine. The problem is with ellipse. They are defined differently in ACad (obviously).